# Resizing images come from android app in PHP

Tags: php, android, image, file-upload

We have an android app and we want to save 2 output images from an image that come from android app by POST in the PHP. 
our problem is that the image type in not specified and all of the images from the app with any type come with .png extension.

As I now, to resizing an image we should now the type of it. 
So how can I use [this class](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) to resizing an unknown type image and save it to a file?

My code:

```
if (isset($_FILES["img1"])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img1"]["tmp_name"] , "../../spl_img/".$gallery_id."-img1.png");

    $address = "../../spl_img/".$gallery_id."-img1.png";
    $resizeObj = new resize($address);
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(80, 'portrait');
    $resizeObj -> saveImage("../../spl_img_thumb/".$gallery_id."-img1.png", 100);
```

The error that I recieve when I want to resize an image with the type of jpg and extension of png:

```
Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/porsojoy/public_html/webservice/spl_img/resize-class.php on line 76

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/porsojoy/public_html/webservice/spl_img/resize-class.php on line 77

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/porsojoy/public_html/webservice/spl_img/resize-class.php on line 217

Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/porsojoy/public_html/webservice/spl_img/resize-class.php on line 246
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the image type with exif methods are more accurate rather than looking file extension 
 after the dot.
You can override the function "openImage()" which is in the class.

```
            private function openImage($file)
        {

           switch (exif_imagetype($file))
            {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;

            }

            return $img;
        }
```

Don't forget to enable the EXIF extension in your php.ini file

On Windows uncomment these lines below:
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll

More Info : [php.net/exif](http://php.net/exif)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype() in /home/porsojoy/public_html/webservice/spl_img/resize-class.php on line 43

Comment: I have this part in my php.ini:  [exif]
; Exif UNICODE user comments are handled as UCS-2BE/UCS-2LE and JIS as JIS. 
; With mbstring support this will automatically be converted into the encoding
; given by corresponding encode setting. When empty mbstring.internal_encoding 
; is used. For the decode settings you can distinguish between motorola and 
; intel byte order. A decode setting cannot be empty.
;exif.encode_unicode = ISO-8859-15
exif.decode_unicode_motorola = "UCS-2BE"
exif.decode_unicode_intel = "UCS-2LE"
;exif.encode_jis = 
exif.decode_jis_motorola = JIS
exif.decode_jis_intel = JIS

Comment: seems like the extensions didn't get enabled. Please check the files (php_mbstring.dll and php_exif.dll ) if they exists in "ext" folder under PHP root.

Comment: It is my php.ini code: ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so"
extension = "php_mbstring.dll"
extension = "php_exif.dll"
extension = "eaccelerator.so"
extension = "suhosin.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "sqlite.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
extension = "ixed.5.3.lin"